# PHP stops executing after the foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a piece of code as below:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$i = 0;
do {
$filename = "links".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $i++ . "-WriteURLs.txt";
} while (file_exists($filename));

$write_URLs = fopen($filename, "w");

foreach ($list_URLs as $htmlIndividual) {
      GetURLs ($htmlIndividual);
      foreach ($URLs as $URLK) {
      fwrite($write_URLs, $URLK ."\n");
    }
echo "Hello World (Inside Foreach Loop) <br>";    
}    
echo "Hello World (First Foreach Loop) <br>";
fclose($write_URLs);
$trimmed = explode("\n",file_get_contents($filename));
foreach ($trimmed as $URLSa) {
    echo "Hello World (Second Foreach Loop) <br>";
}
```

The code writes the URLs to `0-WriteURLs.txt`, `1-WriteURLs.txt`, `2--WriteURLs.txt` and ... and echos the below on every execution of the code:

```
Hello World (Inside Foreach Loop) 
Hello World (Inside Foreach Loop)
```

But, as you can see, the code stops executing the codes after the first foreach loop and it can not echo the `Hello World (First Foreach Loop)` and `Hello World (Second Foreach Loop)` accordingly. Could you please let me know how I can solve this problem? thanks

Note: I added `error_reporting = E_ALL` to `php.ini` file and increased memory limit to `memory_limit = 256M`, but still there is no change.

Comment: turn errors on and tell us what you get

Comment: With proper (better) indentation, you wouldn't have to search for matching curly braces.

Comment: @MrJack, I added `error_reporting = E_ALL` to php.ini file, but still no change,

Comment: @Apiah I think you need some refactoring, 4 loops for such simple task is too much, and `Hello World (First Foreach Loop)` is not even inside of a loop

Comment: How long does all this take to execute, are you timing out, maybe?
(no errors is strange)
What does GetURLs do and why is it not $URLS = GetURLS ?

Comment: @MrJack, I added the GetURLs () function to the question, could you please take a look at the code?

Comment: Looks fine (at least, it should throw errors, nothing else seems to stop it), try var_dump($URLs); right after GetURLs ($htmlIndividual);

How long does it take to execute

Comment: @MrJack, `var_dump($URLs);` echos all the URLs on the browser. it takes ~3 seconds to get the links

Comment: @meda, can you see the question again? thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executing just fine for me printing both Hello World (First Foreach Loop) and
Hello World (Second Foreach Loop) as well as creating the txt file(s).

It's not currently printing "Hello World (Inside Foreach Loop)" as $list_URLs is not defined.

Also try explicitly defining the error reporting
    `error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

in your php file to see all errors and warnings inline. This way it's not permanent across your system, just for the one file.